# Rust sudden execution time spike on 8.5M data size mark

Tags: performance, rust, benchmarking

I'm doing an experiment and found one thing with Rust which I can't understand and reason about.

Here is a test bench code:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

const P: i32 = 200;
const R: i32 = 5;
const PR: i32 = 3;

fn main() {
    run_o_test("seq_search", || {
        fn alg(data: &mut Vec<i32>) {
            for d in data {
                if *d == 100 {
                    *d = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return run_n(alg, 10000000, P, |n: i32| {
            let mut data = vec![0; n.try_into().unwrap()];
            *data.last_mut().unwrap() = 100;
            return data;
        });
    });
}

fn run_o_test(name: &str, test_fn: impl Fn() -> Vec<RunResult>) {
    print!("\x1b[s");
    for i in 0..PR {
        print!("\x1b[u\x1b[Kpreheating {}: {}/{}", name, i + 1, PR);
        stdout().flush().unwrap();
        test_fn();
    }

    for i in 0..R {
        print!("\x1b[u\x1b[K{}: {}/{}", name, i + 1, R);
        stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let res = test_fn();
        export_csv(&format!("{}_data_{}", name, i), res);
    }
    println!();
    stdout().flush().unwrap();
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct RunResult {
    pub n: usize,
    // nanoseconds
    pub time: i64,
}

pub fn run_n<T>(
    test_fn: impl Fn(&mut T),
    max_n: i32,
    points: i32,
    dprep_fn: impl Fn(i32) -> T,
) -> Vec<RunResult> {
    let step = max_n / points;
    let n_batches = max_n / step + 1;
    let mut res = Vec::<RunResult>::with_capacity(n_batches as usize);

    for i in 0..n_batches {
        let n = i * step + 1;
        let mut data = dprep_fn(n);

        let start = std::time::Instant::now();

        std::hint::black_box(test_fn(std::hint::black_box(&mut data)));

        let elapsed = start.elapsed();

        res.push(RunResult {
            n: n.try_into().unwrap(),
            time: elapsed.as_nanos() as i64,
        });
    }

    return res;
}

pub fn export_csv(name: &str, data: Vec<RunResult>) {
    let file_name = format!("gen/data/{}.csv", name);
    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_path(file_name).unwrap();

    wtr.write_record(["n", "time"]).unwrap();
    for d in data {
        wtr.write_record([d.n.to_string(), d.time.to_string()])
            .unwrap();
    }

    wtr.flush().unwrap();
}
```

I have a python script to build charts for the collected execution time and can't describe why there is a sudden spike in execution time somewhere on 8.5M points mark?
Execution time is normalized (Y axis) between 0 to 1, as I don't care about absolute time here.

[image]

I'm not that experienced with Rust, so maybe I don't know something. Things which I thought off, but which don't fit:

1. Implicit memory allocation/deallocation? But it is a constant memory function, there is nothing allocated between measurements time scope.
2. Some special heap management approach with default rust allocator? Maybe, but I didn't find anything to prove that.
3. System related background load? No, I reproduce these results every run with precision. Even loading with real-time scheduler priority, even from Ubuntu recovery mode, where there's minimal environment exists, still the same.
4. Bug in my plotting script? No, everything is as expected linear on 1M, 5M points. + I have another reference from Go execution of the same algorithm, and it is strictly linear.

Any ideas?

**Update 1:**
Reduced plotting code. I'm using default Jupiter notebook in VSCode for that.

```py
import os
import re
import typing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import medfilt
import numpy as np

def read_data(dir: str, pattern: typing.Pattern):
    res = []
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        if re.match(pattern, file):
            res.append(np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(dir, file),
                       skip_header=True, delimiter=','))
    return res

N_INDEX, TIME_INDEX, MEM_INDEX = 0, 1, 2
def unpack_data(data):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    n = data[0, :,N_INDEX]
    time = data[:, :, TIME_INDEX]

    return n, time

def normalize_data(data):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.asarray(x) / np.max(x), 1, np.asarray(data))

def filter_data(data):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: medfilt(x, 11), 1, np.asarray(data))

def mean_data(data):
    return np.mean(data, axis=0)

def std_data(data):
    return np.std(data, axis=0) 

def mae(actual, predicted):
    actual, predicted = np.array(actual), np.array(predicted)
    return np.mean(np.abs(actual - predicted))

def mape(actual, predicted):
    actual, predicted = np.array(actual), np.array(predicted)
    return np.mean(np.abs((actual - predicted) / actual))

def n_formatter(x, pos):
    if x < 1000000:
        return f'{x/1000:.1f}K'
    return f'{x/1000000:.1f}M'

X_TICKS, Y_TICKS = 9, 9
X_MINOR_TICKS, Y_MINOR_TICKS = 25, 25
def prepare_axes(n, ax: plt.Axes):
    n_min, n_max = n[0], n[-1]
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(n_min, n_max, X_TICKS))
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(n_min, n_max, X_MINOR_TICKS), minor=True)

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(n_formatter)

    ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, Y_TICKS))
    ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, Y_MINOR_TICKS), minor=True)
    
    ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
    ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)

    ax.autoscale(False)
    ax.set_xlabel("N")

def plot_mean(n, mean, ax: plt.Axes):
    ax.plot(n, mean, label=f'mean', color='magenta')

def plot_data(n, data, ax: plt.Axes):
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        ax.plot(n, v, label=f'R={i}', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5)

def plot_all(n, data, mean, std, ax: plt.Axes):
    prepare_axes(n, ax)
    plot_data(n, data, ax)
    plot_mean(n, mean, ax)

def On_ideal(n):
    return n, np.linspace(0, 1, len(n))

def plot_ideal(xy: tuple[list[int], list[int]], ax: plt.Axes):
    ax.plot(xy[0], xy[1], label='ideal', linewidth=0.8, color='black')

def run_O(lang: str, type: str, ideal, n, data):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 10), dpi=200)

    norm = normalize_data(data)
    norm_mean, norm_std = mean_data(norm), std_data(norm)

    plot_all(n, norm, norm_mean, norm_std, axs[0])
    axs[0].set_title(f'{lang.capitalize()} raw, {type}')
    axs[0].legend()

    norm_filtered = normalize_data(filter_data(norm))
    norm_filtered_mean, norm_filtered_std = mean_data(norm_filtered), std_data(norm_filtered)

    plot_all(n, norm_filtered, norm_filtered_mean, norm_filtered_std, axs[1])
    plot_ideal(ideal(n), axs[1])
    axs[1].set_title(f'{lang.capitalize()} filtered, {type}')
    axs[1].legend()    

    return fig

def run_On(lang: str, n, data):
    return run_O(lang, "O(n)", On_ideal, n, data)


rust_data = read_data("rust/gen/data", re.compile("seq_search_data_\d\.csv"))
rust_n, rust_time = unpack_data(rust_data)

run_On("rust", rust_n, rust_time);
```

And run the make file:

```
.PHONY: all
all: build run

.PHONY: build
build:
    cargo rustc -r -- --emit asm=/dev/stdout | c++filt > src/main.S

.PHONY: run
run: target/release/rustbigotest
    rm -rf gen && mkdir -p gen/data
    target/release/rustbigotest
```

**Update 2:**
Another possible cause checked:

1. Absolute measurement values i64 or python int type overflow. But no, exported .csv files has 12691595 as maximum value + there is a clear absolute values jump in there from N=8350001, T=4511540 to, N=8400001, T=10456594

**Update 3:**
I've tried jemallocator and the issue gone. Installed it, run measurements, straight line. Commented out allocator replacement with jemalloc again, run, issue returned.
How does it possible? In the loop there are no heap allocations, at least suppose to be none. Is it possible that default allocator somehow sewed two memory addresses underneath and presented it as a single array?

Comment: Can you share the chart building Python script for our convenience?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, It's few hundreds lines of not quality python code. The left chart doesn't tweak data anyhow, it's raw data. Repeats(R) are standalone runs, and mean is just mean from all the Rs.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, added reduced version of plotting code and makefile.

Comment: What CPU did you test on, and what size is its L3 cache?

Comment: @PeterCordes, https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126686/intel-core-i78700-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html

Seems like not a cache either. 12 MB.

Comment: I can't reproduce the jump in your graphs (what OS/distro/glibc are you on?). I did find one curious effect though: With `glibc 2.37`, the allocation isn't pooled but returned to the OS every time if above 33 MB or `n` = 8.2e6. But I can't really think of a good reason a fresh allocation should be a problem (maybe the TLB?). By the way, the L3 size shouldn't matter, most of the `Vec` will never be physically allocated since it's a `vec![0; …]` and only the last page is ever written.

Comment: (Thinking about it: When not pooling allocations, the `munmap` may have to flush the TLB. Maybe that is a problem. I lack the necessary profiling skills to find out.)

Comment: @Caesar Well, as I've stated in Update 3, I also found that this behavior is not reproducible if I switch to jemalloc. If default one is a system allocator, then it should be the reason. But not an expert on this level. 
I'm on Ubuntu 22.0.4. Kernel: kernel 5.19.0-46-generic.

Comment: @Caesar, hard to talk for me for `munmap` and TLB. I am familiar with them, but more as a theory.
Oh and forgot the glibc: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35`

Comment: You can easily follow the `munmap` calls from `strace`. But what exactly the effect on processor state is is also beyond me. Btw, I tried on another machine (Ryzen 3700X, same glibc and linux 6.3.8-arch1-1) and got the [opposite effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENaqN.png). Black magic.

Comment: @Caesar, and if you use jemalloc, do you still have this?

Comment: Not fully. There's definitely a drop at 8.2 M. But that's also my L3 size, so who knows. I give up.